# How do deploy a single build to multiple stages (environments) using github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

### What I have

a simple workflows with two job (Build and Deploy)

```yaml
name: build

on:
  
  push:
    branches: [ master, ci ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest    
    steps:
      - ....

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]
    steps: 
      - ...
```

### What I want

I want to reuse the deploy job and run it twice with different inputs and triggers:

1. input `path: beta` - trigger automatically after build job completes
2. input `path: production` - either trigger manually or require review

What's the simplest way this two stage deployment?

### What I tried:

I extracted `deploy` job to a reusable workflow file and use environment, but I've getting

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/cd.yml (Line: 68, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'environment'

name: build

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, ci ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest    
    steps:
      - ...

  deploy-beta:
    uses: './.github/workflows/deploy_reusable.yml'  
    with:
      path: 'beta/'
    needs: [build]

  deploy-production:
    uses: './.github/workflows/deploy_reusable.yml'  
    with:
      path: 'production/'
    needs: [build]
    environment:
      name: production
```

Comment: A common method to run one job multiple times with varying parameters is [using a matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs), though it's not clear to me what you mean with "input path" in your description.

Answer (score 1):

While you're referencing a reusable workflow in a job, it could contain multiple jobs, all of which might be associated with different environments. Therefore, you cannot use the attribute `environment` in the calling job.

What you want to do instead is to declare a new input `environment` in the reusable workflow and then pass it

```yaml
with:
  path: 'production/'
  environment: 'production'
```

and declare & use it:

```yaml
# ./.github/workflows/deploy_reusable.yml
workflow_call:
  inputs:
    environment:
      type: string

# ...

jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
```

Comment: @Liero does this solve your problem?